# Best combo for a dweller to go to wasteland

Tags: fallout-shelter

I have a question what would be the best combos for a dweller to go to the waste land?

Like maybe endurance and luck or endurance luck and strength or should every thing should be high when a dweller is exploring the wasteland?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a dweller that has maxed out everything, that would work **BEST**. On the other hand, according to what I've observed, Dwellers having higher *Strength* values decrease chances of losing when engaged in fights. *Perception* helps increase chances finding abandoned places. These abandoned places grant high rewards which are affected by *Luck*. *Endurance* obviously contributes to health, a maxed out endurance value will leave you immune to radiation damage. *Charisma* helps increase chances in meeting or befriending people or slaves out there in the wastes. The chances to heal or help these slaves/people are affected by *Intelligence* --which grants high rewards as well, from Caps to Equipments, affected by *Luck*. I think *Agility* helps decrease getting damaged, together with *Strength* and *Endurance* with *Rad-aways* and *Stimpacks* will help you last longer on the wastes. *Luck* basically increase chances in getting a lot of items or rare/r equipments on the field.
Lastly, every stat is important for it what makes a dweller, **SPECIAL**. But in case you haven't maxed out your stats, I had it broken down. So choose your character builds wisely ;)

Comment: You need 11 Endurance for radiation immunity.  10 is fairly high resistance, but it'll still accumulate enough after couple days.